# Difference among derivative (or differential coefficient), derivable (or differentiable) and derivation (or differentiation)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, soft-question, terminology

> **Question:** What is the basic difference among derivative (or differential coefficient), derivable (or differentiable) and derivation (or differentiation) ?

I know it is a very fundamental question (so no one asked it previously). I have an idea about it and I want to share it to others and also interested to know whether my idea is **correct** or **not ?**

---

**My idea:** Let $f(x)$ be a function and when $x$ changes to $\Delta x$ , then $f$ changes to $\Delta f$. Then the limiting value of $\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x}$ as $\Delta x$ tends to zero, provided the limit exists, is called the **derivative** or the **differential coefficient** of $f$ with respect to $x$. It is denoted by $f'(x)$ or $\frac{df}{dx}$. Thus
$$f'(x)=\dfrac{df}{dx}=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\dfrac{\Delta f}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \dfrac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}~.$$
When this limit exists, $f(x)$ is said to be **derivable** or **differentiable** and the process of determining the derivative is called **derivation** or **differentiatio**n.

In short, *derivative refers to a rate of change of a function whereas differentiation is the process of finding the derivative of a function*.

---

Please let me know whether the idea is correct or not and also **suggest if there be any further information to be inserted (or deleted)**.

Comment: The difference is grammatical: derivative is a noun, derivable is an adjective and derivation is a noun that corresponds to a process.

Comment: Sorry to say @MauroALLEGRANZA it is totally different from my question. Your link deals with **differential** and **derivative**, but my question deals with **derivative, derivable  and derivation**, not **differential**.

Comment: So you want to say there is nothing in mathematical perspective ? @GReyes

Comment: Right. There is nothing deep here in my opinion. You derive a derivable  function to get its derivative.